# How can I protect my videos from being stolen?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, flv, jwplayer, piracy-prevention, piracy

I produce movies for local companies and use JWplayer to display them on my website. However, it appears that a few companies have snatched the source of the FLV's ( Amazon's EC2 ), and embedded it on their site.

Is there a practical way to prevent this?

Comment: You can try [streaming protection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protected_Streaming) to make it harder for others to pinch it.

Answer (score 5):

If you're making them available on a website, you cannot prevent them from being stolen. At most you make it a bit harder, but still not impossible.

Comment: Any recommendations on making it *harder* ?

Comment: streaming media servers, watermarking, DRM, requiring registration to get access, etc... but essentially, once the video's bytes leave your server and hit the wire, they're out of your control. heck, even a simple copyright notice would do the trick. "Steal my video and I get to use your guts as tennis racket strings".

Comment: I love the tennis racket strings strategy. I will try that first. Thanks so much Marc

Comment: @Marc, +1 for gratuitous and creative violence.